# Pandas apply - returning dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apply

Here is my example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1':[1,23,4], 'col_2':[3,4,5]})
def test_funct(x, y):
    return pd.DataFrame({'col_3':[8,9], 'col_4':[6,7]})
result = df.apply(lambda row: test_funct(row.col_1, row.col_2), axis = 1)
```

Output looks like:

```
    col_1   col_2
0   (c, o, l, _, 3) (c, o, l, _, 4)
1   (c, o, l, _, 3) (c, o, l, _, 4)
2   (c, o, l, _, 3) (c, o, l, _, 4)
```

This is somewhat unexpected, I thought I would get series/list of dataframes back.

Also the following did not help:

```
result = df.astype(object).apply(lambda row: test_funct(row.col_1, row.col_2), axis = 1)
```

**UPDATE**

Here is even more interesting case. The following function generates dimension error:

```
import numpy as np

def test_funct(x, y):
    return np.zeros(300)
```

While the following one works:

```
import numpy as np

def test_funct(x, y):
    return list(np.zeros(300))
```

Comment: This is not apply suppose to work for , Try for loop and list append

Comment: @ScottBoston I expected series/list of dataframes back